# AWS Pinpoint speed

Tags: twilio, sms, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

So I just hooked up a webhook from AWS SNS which receives messages from AWS PinPoint. I have done some initial testing for SMS texting in the US. I can receive any message on my phone in about 2-5 seconds which was sent from Pinpoint. However when I send a message to the 2-way-sms enabled phone number its taking right around 22 seconds to be received. This is way outside normal texting times between 2 people. Is there any way to improve the time or is there another service that can receive inbound messages and call a webhook with better performance?? I think 5 seconds is already reaching the upper bounds of what is acceptable.

I have looked through the Twilio website but can only find references to average outbound message send times being between 5-10 seconds. I can't find any mention of how long it takes to receive a text message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem may have been that I had my pinpoint project and sns topic in different regions. It is actually running much faster now with phone to webhook delivery times in 1-3 seconds.